# Bash Shell - prompting user to remove files of size 0

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Currently my program will take in a command line argument that will be a reference to a directory that we will be looking in. From there I must create a list of all files within this directory and any subsequent sub directories, remove their path-names (i.e `home/admin/3000/assignment.txt` will become `assignment.txt`) and sort each file by size. Ok that part is done

```
find $location -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | sed 's#.*/##'
```

gives me my sorted list,

now I have to prompt the user if they would like to delete each file of size 0, any tips on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the -size option of find to locate zero byte files. Use rm `-i` option if a  prompt before deleting is required.

```
find $location -type f -size 0 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Comment: rm -i will prompt the user for y or n.  If user enters y or yes the file will be deleted.

Comment: Awsome thanks! cant accept the answer for a few mins still ill accept it when it lets me